# How to successfully exit a task midway within an Airflow dag?

Tags: airflow

I have a dag that checks for files on an FTP server (airflow runs on separate server). If file(s) exist, the file(s) get moved to S3 (we archive here). From there, the filename is passed to a Spark submit job. The spark job will process the file via S3 (spark cluster on different server). I'm not sure if I need to have multiple dags but here's the flow. What I'm looking to do is to only run a Spark job if a file exist in the S3 bucket.

I tried using an S3 sensor but that fails/timeouts after it meets the timeout criteria, therefore the whole dag is set to failed.

```
check_for_ftp_files -> move_files_to_s3 -> submit_job_to_spark -> archive_file_once_done
```

I only want to run everything after the script that does the FTP check ONLY when a file or files were moved into S3.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 different DAGs. One only has the S3 sensor and keeps running, lets say, every 5 minutes. If it finds the file, it triggers the second DAG. The second DAG submits the file to S3 and archives if done.  You can use TriggerDagRunOperator in the first DAG for triggering.

Comment: What happens if it doesn't find a file, wouldn't it exit w/ an error code? Therefore someone would need to retrigger the job, no?

Comment: The first DAG (which has two tasks, S3Sensor and TriggerDagRunOperator) can be scheduled to run every five minutes. This means that the sensor will run every 5 minutes, and if it finds a file, then it triggers the second DAG. Otherwise, it does nothing and reruns after 5 minutes. It doesn't matter if it exits with an error code (you should NOT set depends_on_past to true for first DAG).

Answer (score 0):

The answer Him gave will work. 
Another option is using the "soft_fail" parameter that Sensors have (it is a parameter from the BaseSensorOperator). IF you set this parameter to True, instead of failing a task, it will skip it and all following tasks in the branch will also be skipped.

See [airflow code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-9-stable/airflow/operators/sensors.py) for more info.